# bottom sheet with initial height half of screen and if it scroll then height is increase to full screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a bottom sheet with below code in where i put a height 300.0 but I want increase height to full screen when user scroll ..how can i do that ..please

```
void _showBottomSheet() {
    setState(() {
      _showPersBottomSheetCallBack = null;
    });

    _scaffoldKey.currentState
        .showBottomSheet((context) {
      return new Container(
        height: 300.0,
        color: Colors.greenAccent,
        child: new Center(
          child: new Text("Hi BottomSheet"),
        ),
      );
    })
        .closed
        .whenComplete(() {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _showPersBottomSheetCallBack = _showBottomSheet;
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Check this answer to similar question, https://stackoverflow.com/a/57524472/634355

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The flutter package bottom sheet is *not meant* to occupy the full screen, though a little tweak can produce the behavior you expect. 
If you look at the [BottomSheet constructor](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/1ad538e454c77496fbd068b9e8b5f8b61c2f6d96/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart#L169), you will find the following:

```
  @override
  BoxConstraints getConstraintsForChild(BoxConstraints constraints) {
    return new BoxConstraints(
      minWidth: constraints.maxWidth,
      maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth,
      minHeight: 0.0,
      maxHeight: constraints.maxHeight * 9.0 / 16.0
    );
  }
```

If you remove the 9.0/16.0 height constraint, the bottom sheet will occupy the full screen height.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question. It just shows how to have a full-screen bottom sheet. Granted, this may have been the only option in 2018.

Answer (score 10):

If all you want is a full-screen bottom sheet (as @edmond demonstrates), you can now use `isScrollControlled: true` without having to maintain your own hacked version of `BottomSheet`.

Regardless, the question is about first loading the sheet to half height, with the ability to extend to full height on scroll. For that fine-grained control, you'll still want to use `isScrollControlled: true`, but also you can wrap the content of the modal sheet in `DraggableScrollableSheet`. [This Github comment](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32747#issuecomment-492657937) shows you how to do it, which I'm copying here for reference:

```dart
showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  isScrollControlled: true,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return DraggableScrollableSheet(
      initialChildSize: 0.5, // half screen on load
      maxChildSize: 1,       // full screen on scroll
      minChildSize: 0.25,
      builder: (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollController) {
        return Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: ListView.builder(
            controller: scrollController,
            itemCount: 25,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return ListTile(title: Text('Item $index'));
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  },
);
```