# How can i override only the build method from a class in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation, flutter-packages

I am making a [flutter package](https://github.com/Abhi011999/flutter_colored_progress_indicators) that takes flutter's official implementation of `RefreshIndicator` and adds color functionality to the `CircularProgressIndicator` by animating through the colors.

The official flutter class structure -

1. `ProgressIndicator extends StatefulWidget`
2. `CircularProgressIndicator extends ProgressIndicator`
3. `RefreshProgressIndicator extends CircularProgressIndicator`
4. `RefreshIndicator extends StatefulWidget` and uses `RefreshProgressIndicator` in the `build` method.

**There is a `valueColor` property in RefreshProgressIndicator which i need to change.
The build method in RefreshIndicator's state returns `RefreshProgressIndicator` with its own pre-defined values, along with the `valueColor` property defaulting to App's theme color.**

For example - I already implemented colored `CircualrProgressIndicator` [here](https://github.com/Abhi011999/flutter_colored_progress_indicators/blob/master/lib/src/ColoredCircularProgressIndicator.dart).

**Please have a look at the package to get the basic idea of what i am trying to do.**

How can i implement this by referencing the already defined classes without copying the entire class from the official flutter repo ?

---

A question like this is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53084411/flutter-how-to-adjust-override-properties-of-the-flutter-core-code-without-copy) but i wanted to approach this problem in a different and more efficient way (if there is).