# how to set showModalBottomSheet to full height?

Tags: dart, flutter

I use `showRoundedModalBottomSheet`, how can I adjust this modal height till the appbar?

[image]

Comment: I don't think it is possible but you can implement the Full-Screen Dialog.

Comment: it is possible drag down to close the fullscreen dialog?

Comment: You can use 
GestureDetector to do so.

Comment: how to transparent the appbar on fullscreen dialog? and edge the body of scaffold, so its will look full height of my post image before?

Answer (score 228, accepted):

**[Update]**

In `showModalBottomSheet(...)` set the property `isScrollControlled:true`.

It will make bottomSheet to full height.

---

**[Original answer]**

You can Implement the FullScreenDialog instead.

Flutter Gallery app has an example  of [FullScreenDialog](https://github.com/flutter/gallery/blob/74d9d92883c6ca10742c44df309f065289cf2f55/lib/demos/material/dialog_demo.dart)

You can open your Dialog using below code:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute<Null>(
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Dialog();
      },
    fullscreenDialog: true
  ));
```

Check this blog [post](https://marcinszalek.pl/flutter/flutter-fullscreendialog-tutorial-weighttracker-ii/) too for more:

Hope it will help you.

Comment: how to transparent the appbar on fullscreen dialog? and edge the body of scaffold, so its will look full height of my post image before?

Comment: That's another question.
You can use to make your color of the Appbar transparent.

Comment: its will become black.if set all base material color to transparant it will make another problem

Comment: @ibhavikmakwana the popup is over status bar, do you know how to adjust it?

Comment: Try using a `SafeArea` widget.

Comment: @ibhavikmakwana Seems like the example is removed

Comment: I don't know why my comment is not showing it here :-| but I have updated a link. Thanks.

Answer (score 226):

You can control the height by using **FractionallySizedBox** and setting the **isScrollControlled** to **true**.

```
showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    isScrollControlled: true,
    builder: (context) {
      return FractionallySizedBox(
        heightFactor: 0.9,
        child: Container(),
      );
    });
```

Comment: isScrollControlled solved my issue... it enables dynamic showModalBottomSheet height

Comment: It works , but , the drag-to-dismiss behavior is gone now !!!

Comment: @zulkarnainshah i used `showModalBottomSheet` with `isScrollControlled: true` several times and had no problems at all. The drag-to-dismiss still working fine.

Comment: I've just looking for this answer . I wanted to make the dialog full screen but have some padding at top.

Answer (score 41):

If you call `showModalBottomSheet()` with `isScrollControlled: true`, then the dialog will be allowed to occupy the whole height.

To adjust the height to the content, you can proceed as usually, for example, using `Container` and `Wrap` widgets.

Example:

```
final items = <Widget>[
  ListTile(
    leading: Icon(Icons.photo_camera),
    title: Text('Camera'),
    onTap: () {},
  ),
  ListTile(
    leading: Icon(Icons.photo_library),
    title: Text('Select'),
    onTap: () {},
  ),
  ListTile(
    leading: Icon(Icons.delete),
    title: Text('Delete'),
    onTap: () {},
  ),
  Divider(),
  if (true)
    ListTile(
      title: Text('Cancel'),
      onTap: () {},
    ),
];

showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext _) {
    return Container(
      child: Wrap(
        children: items,
      ),
    );
  },
  isScrollControlled: true,
);
```

Answer (score 30):

What worked for me was returning the modal's content wrapped in a `DraggableScrollableSheet`:

```
showModalBottomSheet(
  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  context: context,
  isScrollControlled: true,
  isDismissible: true,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return DraggableScrollableSheet(
      initialChildSize: 0.75, //set this as you want
      maxChildSize: 0.75, //set this as you want
      minChildSize: 0.75, //set this as you want
      expand: true,
      builder: (context, scrollController) {
        return Container(...); //whatever you're returning, does not have to be a Container
      }
    );
  }
)
```

Answer (score 27):

I guess the easiest way is:

```
showModalBottomSheet(
      isScrollControlled: true,
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => Wrap(children: [YourSheetWidget()]),
    );
```

Answer (score 7):

1. You open class BottomSheet in library of flutter and change maxHeight

from

```
BoxConstraints getConstraintsForChild(BoxConstraints constraints) {
return BoxConstraints(
  minWidth: constraints.maxWidth,
  maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth,
  minHeight: 0.0,
  maxHeight: constraints.maxHeight * 9.0 / 16.0
);}
```

to

```
BoxConstraints getConstraintsForChild(BoxConstraints constraints) {
return BoxConstraints(
  minWidth: constraints.maxWidth,
  maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth,
  minHeight: 0.0,
  maxHeight: constraints.maxHeight
);}
```

2. You can create a new class with other name and copy source code from class BottomSheet and change maxHeight

Answer (score 4):

The default height for BottomSheet is half the screen size. If you want your BottomSheet to EXPAND according to your content DYNAMICALLY.

```
showModalBottomSheet<dynamic>(
isScrollControlled: true,
context: context,
builder: (BuildContext bc) {
  return Wrap(
      children: <Widget>[...]
  )
 }
)
```

This will automatically expand the BottomSheet according to the content inside.

Answer (score 4):

You can control the height by using `FractionallySizedBox` and set `useSafeArea` to `true` to get the accurate useable height without notch.

```
 showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      useSafeArea: true,
      builder: (_) {
        return FractionallySizedBox(
          heightFactor: 0.85,
          child: Container(),
        );
      },
    );
```

Answer (score 3):

Using constraints and isScrollControlled fields like this:

```
 showModalBottomSheet(
                  context: context,
                   constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight:  context.mediaQuerySize.height * .9, maxHeight: context.mediaQuerySize.height * .9),
                  isScrollControlled: true,
                  builder: (context) => YourWidget(),
                )
```

but we should implement both minHeight and maxHeight.

Answer (score 3):

A way to do it without `isScrollControlled: true` (which adds a scrollable field and can mess with layout)

```
return showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      useSafeArea: true,
      constraints: BoxConstraints(
        maxHeight: double.infinity,
      ),
      scrollControlDisabledMaxHeightRatio: 1,
      builder: (context) {
        // your widget
      },
    );
```

you need to both allow the constraints to take up any space, and set the scrollControlDisabledMaxHeightRatio to 1 to allow it to go full screen
useSafeArea stops it from expanding over the status bar

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `DraggableScrollableSheet` to adjust the height of the bottom sheet and handle scrolling :

```
  showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  useRootNavigator: true,
  isScrollControlled: true,
  enableDrag: true,
  builder: (_) {
    return DraggableScrollableSheet(
      minChildSize: minSize,
      maxChildSize: maxSize,
      expand: false,
      initialChildSize: initSize,
      builder: (context, scrollController) {
        return YourWidget();
      },
    );
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify this method in the definition of the bottom sheet. Normally, it is 9.0, but as you can see here I changed it to 13.0. 16.0 is full screen.

```
@override
      BoxConstraints getConstraintsForChild(BoxConstraints constraints) {
        return BoxConstraints(
          minWidth: constraints.maxWidth,
          maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth,
          minHeight: 0.0,
          maxHeight: isScrollControlled
            ? constraints.maxHeight
            : constraints.maxHeight * 13.0 / 16.0,
        );
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the contents in a Container and provide height to full height

```
  await showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(30), topRight: Radius.circular(30))),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
         return Container(
             height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
             child: ListView(
         )
      )
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
showModalBottomSheet(
    isScrollControlled: true,
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
        return DraggableScrollableSheet(
            builder: (
                BuildContext context,
                // Use scrollController for listView inside content
                ScrollController scrollController,
            ) {
                // Your content here <---
                return Scaffold();
              },
            initialChildSize: 0.95,
            maxChildSize: 0.95,
            minChildSize: 0.90,
        );
    },
);
```