# How to Move bottomsheet along with keyboard which has textfield(autofocused is true)?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to make a bottomsheet that has a text field and autofocus is set to true so that the keyboard pops up. But, bottomsheet is overlapped by the keyboard. Is there a way to move bottomsheet above the keyboard?

```
Padding(
  padding:
      EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
  child: Column(children: <Widget>[
    TextField(
      autofocus: true,
      decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Title'),
    ),
    TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Details!'),
      keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
      maxLines: 4,
    ),
    TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Additional details!'),
      keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
      maxLines: 4,
    ),]);
```

Comment: There's also a few open issues on Github: [main issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18564) and [another](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17861) with a comment that offers an animated solution.

Comment: For me, it's fixed simply by adding a `Padding` element as the last child of `Column` and set its padding as `padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets`

Comment: @Huy thank you. you should put your comment to answer.

Answer (score 428, accepted):

- **To fix this issue**

1. All you need is to use Keyboard padding using `MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom`
2. For more insurance, set `isScrollControlled = true` of the `BottomSheetDialog` this will allow the bottom sheet to take the full required height.

- Note if your `BottomSheetModel` is `Column` make sure you add                `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min` otherwise the sheet will cover the whole screen.
- **Example**

```dart
showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        isScrollControlled: true,
        builder: (context) => Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
          child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),
                    child: Text('Enter your address',
                        style: TextStyles.textBody2),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 8.0,
                  ),
                  TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'adddrss'
                      ),
                      autofocus: true,
                    ),                 
                ],
              ),
        ));
```

- **UPDATED**

Flutter 2.2 breaks the changes again!” Now you need to give bottom padding once again so the keyboard doesn't overlap the bottomsheet.

Comment: After applying this, the bottom sheet took up the whole screen. Worked around it through placing a static value for the height property of my Container widget for the bottom sheet.

Comment: What is the child of the bottom sheet?

Comment: @Abed I tried your method. Is it not working for my problem.. please check https://stackoverflow.com/q/58240592/8822337

Comment: 2021! you don't need it now: `padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets`

Comment: new flutter lib dont need that, it will taking whole screen

Comment: Adding "isScrollControlled = true" on showModalBottomSheet and "mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min" on Column widgets solved my all the issues. Thanks Abed.

Comment: Also make sure that the height of the builder widget isn't fixed

Comment: How to add auto-scroll when an input gets focused in a scrollable modal?

Comment: Are these solutions still valid? this did not work for me. @Abed

Comment: Simple and efficient solution

Comment: Note that for flutter 3.1.0, if what is returned by the builder is a Container with height defined, the height of the bottom sheet will not update.

Answer (score 209):

Just add:

- `isScrollControlled: true` to showModalBottomSheet
- `padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets` to widget in builder
- column/wrap both works

```
showModalBottomSheet<void>(
  isScrollControlled: true,
  context: context,
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
        topRight: Radius.circular(30.0)),
  ),
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
        padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,
        child: Container(
            child: Wrap(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  hintText: 'Enter a search term'),
            ),
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  hintText: 'Enter a search term'),
            ),
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  hintText: 'Enter a search term'),
            ),
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  hintText: 'Enter a search term'),
            )
          ],
        )));
  },
);
```

**Update Feb 25 2020 better solution**

```
showModalBottomSheet(
 isScrollControlled: true,
 builder: (BuildContext context) {

    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        padding:
            EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 0.0), // content padding
          child: Form(...)) // From with TextField inside


});
```

Comment: Just a note for everyone: For the question asked, Wrap widget is not required since the problem is about the bottomSheet being able to move above the keyboard and not the content of the bottom sheet it self.

Answer (score 44):

In Order to focus on the Keyboard in  `BottomSheet` - Wrap `TextField` in Padding Widget as like Below e.g Code:

```
showModalBottomSheet(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) {
                return Container(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
                    child: TextField(
                      autofocus: true,
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              });
```

Comment: Hi Thanks. This works for two child fields but not when we add a third field. I have edited question with my code sample.

Comment: @ManjunathRao You probably need to add "Key" to textfield to keep them unique in order to get more than 2. Let me know if this helped

Comment: `BottomSheet` - has the `maxHeight: constraints` as the Fields are Increasing height won't increase. You can use `ListView` in BottomSheet to make fields visible in scroll. or you can try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53311553/how-to-set-showmodalbottomsheet-to-full-height

Comment: @ManjunathRao - you wont get more than two Fields in BottomSheet as such - Due to `maxHeight: constraints`

Answer (score 25):

In the latest version of flutter, you can move your bottomSheet using `isScrollControlled` property/named parameter. Suppose i have a function(_showModal) which will invoke when a button is pressed. And i define the bottom sheet functionality on that function.

```
void _showModal() {
  showModalBottomSheet(
    isScrollControlled: true,
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextField(// your other code),
          SizedBox(height: 5.0),
          TextField(// your other code),
          SizedBox(height: 5.0),
          TextField(// your other code),
        ]
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Here a ModalBottomSheet will appear but with fullscreen of height. And you don't need that height. So, you need to Column's `mainAxisSize` to `min`.

```
Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  // your other code
)
```

Fullscreen of height problem is solved, but ModalBottomSheet doesn't move to top when keyboard is appeared. Ok, to solve this issue you need to set `viewInsets` bottom padding to your ModalBottomSheet. So to set padding we need to wrap our Column with Container or Padding and then set the padding. The final code will look like this

```
void _showModal() {
  showModalBottomSheet(
    isScrollControlled: true,
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
        ),
        // You can wrap this Column with Padding of 8.0 for better design
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(// your other code),
            SizedBox(height: 5.0),
            TextField(// your other code),
            SizedBox(height: 5.0),
            TextField(// your other code),
          ]
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Hope your issue is fixed. Thank's

Comment: Work like a charm...!

Answer (score 24):

Package: https://pub.dev/packages/modal_bottom_sheet

Wrap your widget into Padding and set padding like this ==>

```
padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets // viewInsets will decorate your screen
```

You can use
showMaterialModalBottomSheet or showModalBottomSheet or showCupertinoModalBottomSheet

```
showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        barrierColor: popupBackground,
        isScrollControlled: true, // only work on showModalBottomSheet function
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(borderRadiusMedium),
                topRight: Radius.circular(borderRadiusMedium))),
        builder: (context) =>  Padding(
            padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,
            child: Container(
                   height: 400, //height or you can use Get.width-100 to set height
                   child: <Your Widget here>
             ),)),)
```

[image: before]

[image: after]

Comment: hi Can u please tell which Font have you used for your app ??

Comment: It's Ubuntu. You can download it from here -> https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Ubuntu

Answer (score 21):

Try this

My Solution is

- Use `isScrollControlled: true`
- Add Padding

  ```dart
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom)
  ```
- Wrap your layout in `SingleChildScrollView`

**SAMPLE CODE**

```dart
Future<void> future = showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  isDismissible: true,
  isScrollControlled: true,
  backgroundColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.2),
  builder: (context) => SingleChildScrollView(
    child: GestureDetector(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom
        ),
        child: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              // add your widget here
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
    ),
  )
);
```

Comment: the point of SingleChildScrollView wrapping is important. thanks

Comment: This helped in maintaining the symmetry .. Thanks

Answer (score 13):

I got it fixed by increasing the height of the child widget when the keyboard gets opened.
initially value of MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom will be 0 it will change when the keyboard gets focused.

```
showModalBottomSheet<void>(
      enableDrag: true,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Card(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2 +
                MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                TextField(),
                TextField(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
```

Comment: That's the behavior I wanted! Congrats!

Answer (score 13):

For people who can't solve their problem trying all the answers. These answers are correct but not so clear.

#### When using

`MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom)`

make sure your context variable is using the one provided by bottom sheet builder property.

`builder :(**c**)=>MediaQuery.of(**c**)`

Comment: thanks, just change to my showModalBottomSheet context fix the problem.

Answer (score 12):

**UPDATED 2021 May flutter 2.2!**
Now you need to give bottom padding. The below written was a bug.

**UPDATED 2020!**

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57515977/12279445) is true, but you don't have to give bottom padding now!
Find and delete this line:

`padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets`

Comment: Thank you, Good hint. Your solution works for me (Flutter stable revision 60bd88df91). But checkout the ref a5262 (Revert "[showModalBottomSheet] fix: showModalBottomSheet does not move along keyboard") at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/commits/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart. So I think we may need to track issue in the upcoming updates of Flutter.

Comment: Confirmed, flutter 2.2 broke this again and you need the MediaQuery again.

Answer (score 7):

Add this after the last widget of your bottom sheet

```
Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom:MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom))
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this.

```
showModalBottomSheet(
        isScrollControlled: true,
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AnimatedPadding(
              padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
              curve: Curves.decelerate,
              child: Container(
                  child: Wrap(
                children: [
                  TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "1"),
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "2"),
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "3"),
                  ),
                ],
              )));
        },
      )
```

Answer (score 6):

You should to use this then,

```
showModalBottomSheet(
    isScrollControlled: true,
    context: context,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      // <-- for border radius
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
        topRight: Radius.circular(10.0),
      ),
    ),
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return SingleChildScrollView(
        padding:
            EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
        child: drunkenWidget()...

//BTW, Never ever Drink
```

Answer (score 6):

```
showModalBottomSheet(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
      ),
      context: context,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      builder: (builder) {
        return Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 40,
          padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,
          child: <Your Widget Here>,
        );
      },
    );
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

After combining different solutions I got this:

if you don't want it to be **Full screen** and don't want to use the **Padding** workaround use

```dart
  showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(20)),
      ),
      enableDrag: true,
      isDismissible: true,
      useRootNavigator: true,
      builder: (BuildContext ctx) {
        return Scaffold( // use CupertinoPageScaffold for iOS
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true, // important
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Form(
              child: Container(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    TextFormField(),
                    TextFormField(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
```

on **Flutter (Channel master, v1.15.3-pre.37, on Mac OS X 10.15.2 19C57, locale en-US)**

Answer (score 4):

If you have full screen or fixed size `showModalBottomSheet` don't use `padding` it will not solve your problem.  Use `margin` instead of `padding` like this :

```
  showModalBottomSheet(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            return Container(
                marign: EdgeInsets.only(
                    bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
                child: TextField()
            );
          });
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using  `builder: (BuildContext context) { }` in the builder, use `builder: (context) { }`

With this solution my modal bottom sheet sticks to the statusbar (acts like `Scaffold` with `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false`) and allows to view all the form fields and scroll through the form if it is still needed to view bottom text fields.

For more details, here's the link from where I found the solution- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18564#issuecomment-602604778

Answer (score 4):

In my case it worked only when added this line to `Scaffold` inside the page who is calling `showModalBottomSheet`:

```
Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
  ..
),
```

And for sure, you need to add `padding` inside the `showModalBottomSheet` 's `builder`:

```
showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  isScrollControlled: true,
  builder: (context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
      ),
      child: Container(), // Your layout goes here..
    );
  }
);
```

Comment: This no longer works for me in Flutter 3.3.10. Anything that would prevent this from working?

Answer (score 3):

If you still have not found your issue. So I think you have missed in your **BuilderContext**. Sometimes when you implement modalBottomSheet it will give you only the ***context*** parameter. So add context with BuildContext.

```
 builder: (BuildContext context) {  //-Here is your issue add BuilderContext class name as it as 
          return Padding(
            padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
                child: new Container(
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the `Form` with a `Scaffold` widget, and then wrap the `TextFormField` with a `SingleChildScrollView` :

```
 return Container(
          height: screenHeight * .66,
          child: Scaffold(
             body: Form(
               key: _form,
               child: SingleChildScrollView(
                 child:TextFormField()
               )
              )
             )
           )
```

Comment: `Scaffold(child:`?

Answer (score 2):

Fount this on [github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18564#issuecomment-419804357)

```
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
  child: TextField()
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your router link modal bottom sheet

```
 showModalBottomSheet(              
     context: context,
     isScrollControlled: true,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Messagescr();
      }
    );
```

And remove this line also in your Scaffold :

```
resizeToAvoidBottomInset : false,
```

Answer (score 1):

```
showModalBottomSheet(
 isScrollControlled: true,
 builder: (BuildContext context) {

    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        padding:
            EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0), // content padding
          child: Container())});
```

Note : This line does all the magic

Answer (score 1):

Before trying any of the above solutions don't forget to add `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false` to the parent `Scaffold` widget.

Answer (score 1):

all solutions are good.
but for modals that have a fixed header and a long body with a text field in bottom I recommended this solution. that height is more than **screen.height/2**

```
 showMaterialModalBottomSheet<void>(
// isScrollControlled: true,

context: context,

backgroundColor: Colors.white,
shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
  // side: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
      topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
      topRight: Radius.circular(10)),
),
builder: (BuildContext context) {
  return Padding(
  padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,
  child: Container(
      height: height - MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: ColorConstants.background,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
            topRight: Radius.circular(10)),
      ),
      padding:EdgeInsets.all(0),
      child: Wrap(
        children: [
       // fixed header
          Container(
            height: 56,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
            
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(10)),
            ),
         
          ),
          SizedBox(
              height: height -
                  56 -
                  MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
              child: (scrollable body with textfield))
        ],
      )));
    },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../weight/boostrap/flutter_bootstrap.dart';
import '../weight/boostrap/bootstrap_widgets.dart';

/*
  TextEditingController txtname = TextEditingController();
          showModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            isScrollControlled: true,
            shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                topRight: Radius.circular(20),
              ),
            ),
            builder: (context) => SingleChildScrollView(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom),
              child: new AddItem(
                  tektk: 'Category',
                  tektd: 'Add',
                  txtname: txtname,
                  ismultik:false,
                  onPressed: () {}),
            ),
          );
    */
class AddItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const AddItem(
      {Key? key,
      required this.ismultik,
      required this.tektd,
      required this.tektk,
      required this.txtname,
      required this.onPressed})
      : super(key: key);
  final bool ismultik;
  final String tektk;
  final String tektd;
  final VoidCallback? onPressed;
  final TextEditingController txtname;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final MediaQueryData mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    bootstrapGridParameters(gutterSize: 10);
    return Padding(
      padding: mediaQueryData.viewInsets,
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 90.0, left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            ListTile(
              trailing: SizedBox.fromSize(
                size: Size(35, 35),
                child: ClipOval(
                  child: Material(
                    color: Colors.indigo,
                    child: InkWell(
                      splashColor: Colors.white,
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(Icons.close, color: Colors.white),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            BootstrapRow(height: 0, children: [
              BootstrapCol(
                sizes: 'col-md-12',
                child: TextField(
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(
                    border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
                    labelText: tektk,
                  ),
                  keyboardType: ismultik == true
                      ? TextInputType.multiline
                      : TextInputType.text,
                  maxLines: null,
                  minLines: 1,
                  controller: txtname,
                ),
              ),
              BootstrapCol(
                sizes: 'col-md-12',
                child: ElevatedButton(
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: Colors.green, // background
                      onPrimary: Colors.white, // foreground
                    ),
                    onPressed: onPressed,
                    child: Text(tektd)),
              ),
            ]),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you need to use comments to describe your code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Abed's answer stated the correct solution to your specific question. However, there are many other tricky issues to solve when creating a bottom sheet. Here is my complete working bottom sheet creator function, which will hopefully help someone.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Future Function() openBottomSheet(BuildContext context, Widget child,
    {String? title}) {
  return () => showModalBottomSheet(
        // Don't let bottom sheet extend past the top of the safe area
        useSafeArea: true,
        context: context,
        // Round the top of the bottom sheet
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
        ),
        // Add scrollbar when necessary
        isScrollControlled: true,
        builder: (context) => ScrollableWidget(
          child: Container(
            // Move bottom sheet above on-screen keyboard, if keyboard is open
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                // Add back button at top left of bottom sheet (since it's
                // not obvious that sheet can be swiped down to close it)
                const BackButton(),
                Padding(
                  // Pad the main widget (larger padding on the top to leave
                  // space for the back button)
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 35.0, 20.0, 25.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      // Make content full-width, so that main widget is
                      // centered even if it doesn't expand
                      Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        children: const [SizedBox(height: 0)],
                      ),
                      // Add title text to top of bottom sheet, if provided
                      title == null
                          ? Container()
                          : Column(
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  title,
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 18),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(height: 8),
                              ],
                            ),
                      // Add the main widget
                      child,
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
}

/// A scrollable widget with a scrollbar that is shown when necessary
class ScrollableWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScrollableWidget({super.key, required this.child});

  final Widget child;

  @override
  State<ScrollableWidget> createState() => _ScrollableWidgetState();
}

class _ScrollableWidgetState extends State<ScrollableWidget> {
  final controller = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scrollbar(
      thumbVisibility: true,
      thickness: 15,
      radius: const Radius.circular(8),
      controller: controller,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        // Same controller must be used on Scrollbar and SingleChildScrollView
        controller: controller,
        child: widget.child,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Just add

```
if (_isEditing) SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
```

under the keyboard and hide all other content below the textfield with

```
if (!_isEditing) Widget(...),
```