# Keyboard pushes modalBottomSheet out of the bounds, resizeToAvoidBottomInset not working

Tags: flutter, keyboard, flutter-layout, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

I ran into problem in a Flutter application. The keyboard pushes the modal bottom sheet up even if the Scaffold has **resizeToAvoidBottomInset** set to **false**. I want the modal bottom sheet to remain at its initial position. I will show you my code for displaying the modal bottom sheet and I will attach a video to show you the bug.

```
Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
    key: _scaffoldKey,
    body: ...
)

showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  isScrollControlled: true,
  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  builder: (context) => Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.8,
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: const Radius.circular(25.0),
          topRight: const Radius.circular(25.0),
        ),
      ),
      child: SearchPlace((place, alreadyExists) {
        Navigator.pop(context);
        didSelectPlace(place, alreadyExists);
      })),
);
```

[image]

Hope you can help me, thanks!

Comment: Not sure, but one thing i stumbled upon is that if you have multiple Scaffolds in the hierarchy, then you need to add resizeToAvoidBottomInset to all of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, so I found a solution for this issue myself.

I wanted the modal bottom sheet to occupy 80% of the screen, but it was always pushed by the keyboard.
In order to fix this I wrapped the main **Container** in a **Column** widget and added an additional transparent Container with a **GestureDetector** (to dismiss the bottom sheet) having the height 20% of the screen. After that I wrapped the Column in a **SingleChildScrollView**. Now everything works as expected! I added a video below.

```
showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    isScrollControlled: true,
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  builder: (context) => SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(children: [
      GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2,
        ),
      ),
      Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.8,
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: const Radius.circular(25.0),
              topRight: const Radius.circular(25.0),
            ),
          ),
          child: SearchPlace((place, alreadyExists) => {
                Navigator.pop(context),
                didSelectPlace(place, alreadyExists),
              })),
    ]),
  ),
);
```

[image]

Comment: Worked perfectly for me, thanks!! Keyboard does not push it anymore

Answer (score 1):

Similar issue solved here
Please have a look -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/68660719/7760245

or use

```
padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets // viewInsets will decorate your screen
```

full code ->

```
showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        barrierColor: popupBackground,
        isScrollControlled: true, // only work on showModalBottomSheet function
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(borderRadiusMedium),
                topRight: Radius.circular(borderRadiusMedium))),
        builder: (context) =>  Padding(
            padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,
            child: Container(
                   height: 400, //height or you can use Get.width-100 to set height
                   child: <Your Widget here>
             ),)),)
```

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]