# Flutter overflow on TextFormField

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Is there a way to configure an overflow setting on a TextFormField in flutter? I have a TextFormField that triggers a bottomSheet onClick. From the Bottom Sheet, the value of the TextEditingController is changed, and sometimes it may overflow the field, but I cannot set it to have a specific behavior- such as ellipsis.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Move bottomsheet along with keyboard which has textfield(autofocused is true)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53869078/how-to-move-bottomsheet-along-with-keyboard-which-has-textfieldautofocused-is-t)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.