# showModalBottomSheet does not move along with keyboard in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am newer in flutter. I searched this issue in the internet. but, showModalbottomsheet does not move along with keyboard.

I add `isScrollControlled : true` in showModalbottomsheet, and `padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,` is added to TextField. I try to position of `padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,` to other Widget. but it also doesn't work.

the keyboard cover bottomsheet. help me!!

this is my code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';

class B20 extends StatefulWidget {
  const B20({Key? key, required this.postNo}) : super(key: key);
  final String postNo;

  @override
  B20State createState() => B20State();
}

class B20State extends State<B20> {
  Map<String, Object> result = {};
  final TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();

  void _showModalBottomSheet(BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(20)),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        context: context,
        isScrollControlled: true, // add isScrollControlled
        builder: (context) => _commentBottomSheetContainer(context));
  }

  Widget _commentBottomSheetContainer(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            color: Color(0xffffffff),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
              topRight: Radius.circular(20),
            )),
        child: Padding(
          padding:
              EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom), //add padding
          child: TextField(
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            autofocus: true,
            controller: _textEditingController,
            maxLines: 10,
            minLines: 1,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'Noto_Sans_KR',
                fontSize: 13.sp,
                color: const Color(0xffABACB2),
              ),
              border: InputBorder.none,
              focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
              enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
              errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
              disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
              hintText: '댓글을 남겨주세요',
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.w, -20.h, 15.w, 0.h),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }

  
  Widget _commentContainer(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        _showModalBottomSheet(context);
      },
      child: Text(
        '댓글을 남겨주세요',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontFamily: 'Noto_Sans_KR',
          fontSize: 13.sp,
          color: const Color(0xffABACB2),
        ),
        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
        softWrap: false,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
      },
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            body: _commentContainer(context),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no problem in code. Code works in my PC. Try to restart app and check again.

Comment: @Yashraj restart app. but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find my problem.

in main.dart. I delete `useInheritedMediaQuery: true,`

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScreenUtilInit(
      designSize: const Size(375, 812),
      minTextAdapt: true,
      builder: (_, child) {
        return MaterialApp(
          useInheritedMediaQuery: true, // this make problem. I delete it. it work.
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: MultiProvider(
            providers: [
              ChangeNotifierProvider(
                  create: (BuildContext context) => BottomNavigationProvider()),
              ChangeNotifierProvider(
                  create: (BuildContext context) => B10Provider()),
              ChangeNotifierProvider(
                  create: (BuildContext context) => B20Provider()),
              ChangeNotifierProvider(
                  create: (BuildContext context) => C10Provider()),
              ChangeNotifierProvider(
                  create: (BuildContext context) => C20Provider()),
              ChangeNotifierProvider(
                  create: (BuildContext context) => D10Provider()),
            ],
            child: Home(),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `isScrollControlled = true` to `BottomSheetDialog` it'll allow the bottom sheet to take the full required height which gives more insurance that TextField is not covered by the keyboard.

Add Keyboard `padding` using `MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom`

For reference https://blog.sombex.com/2021/06/move-bottomsheet-along-with-keyboard-in-flutter.html

This question already has the answer in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57515977/11789675)

Comment: see my code. i try it already. but it dosen't work.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the problem.I am facing this issue in latest flutter version and latest flutter_screenutil package.The problem is occured for  inheritedMediaQuery which hide the content of the bottomsheet. if you are using flutter_screenutil maybe you are facing this issue.

so I just add

```
    ScreenUtilInit(
      useInheritedMediaQuery: true, // add this line and see the magic
      designSize: const Size(414, 896),
      minTextAdapt: true,
      splitScreenMode: true,
    )
```