# How to Move bottomsheet along with keyboard which has textfield(autofocused is true)? lates flutter version 3.10.4

Tags: flutter, dart

```
showModalBottomSheet(
    useSafeArea: true,
    isScrollControlled: true,
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    context: context,
    builder: (context){
      return Consumer<OnBoardingProvider>(
          builder: (context, provider,child) {
            return Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
              // padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: <MyWidget>}))
```

- keyboard hides bottom sheet? Can any one help me. I am new in flutter development

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Move bottomsheet along with keyboard which has textfield(autofocused is true)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53869078/how-to-move-bottomsheet-along-with-keyboard-which-has-textfieldautofocused-is-t)

Comment: What is your device? This works fine on my iPhone simulator

Comment: No, That didn't help @Edson

Comment: Its works on flutter 3.10.1 version but not for 3.10.4 @OlegBezr

Comment: Got it. It also works on 3.10.2 that I use. I would recommend you to avoid 3.10.4. Hopefully, the Flutter team will have it fixed in the next releases. In case you don't know about it, I highly recommend you using https://fvm.app/ to have several versions of flutter installed and easily switch between them. It really helps me with my everyday work on several projects