# Flutter dont close bottomSheet on BottomNavigationBar tap

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem with a BottomNavigationBar. My app has two screens and one of them has a bottom sheet that doesn't hide on disposing of the first screen when I'm tapping on the icon of the second screen. BottomNavigationBar works normally and screens switch, but how to hide the bottom sheet of the first screen when shown the second screen I have no ideas. Could you help me solve that?

Calling:

```
void _showForm(int id) async {
        showBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            elevation: 5,
            builder: (context) => BottomSheetSwitch(_refreshJournals, id));
      }
```

Closing (inside bottom sheet):

```
Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

P.S. I couldn't solve that problem, so I change showBottomSheet to showModalBottomSheet like that was in: [how to set showModalBottomSheet to full height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53311553/how-to-set-showmodalbottomsheet-to-full-height)

Comment: Can you include some-snippet how you are calling and closing the bottom sheet, and the snippet will reproduce the same issue you are currently facing

Comment: Can you add your code snippet

Comment: Please share your code snippet

Answer (score 0):

You can try to provide a key to the stateful widget of BottomSheet and access that key's context, just use the Navigator's pop method on tap or change of the screen. It might help you.

You can use it like

```
Navigator.of(key.currentContext).pop();
```

Else call the function of your BottomSheet using the key. Like as below

1. Declare GlobalKey with state in your currentWidget.

> `GlobalKey<BottomSheetWidgetState> closeKey = GlobalKey();`

2. Declare function closeBottomSheet in your bottomsheet widget state.

> `void closeBottomSheet() { Navigator.of(conext).pop(); }`

3. Call the function using the key.

> `closeKey.currentState.closeBottomSheet();`

And done.

Comment: Im thinking about that (Tried to set state on dispose and change bool value of showing). But thought there might be a better way.

Comment: You can use it like Navigator.of(key.currentContext).pop();

Comment: I tried it before wrote here. It thrown exception((

Comment: Please try with updated answer

Comment: Dhalloo, thank you for help, but no that don't work for me(

How you sad:
1) I add: `GlobalKey<State<BottomSheetSwitch>> closeKey= GlobalKey();`
2) I declared function
3) In `closeKey.currentState` I havent method  `closeBottomSheet()`

Also `closeKey.currentState` always null and throw exception

Comment: @samfisher you give the wrong type of key. BottomSheetSwitch must be some stateful widget and you need to provide its state class name. Also, you need to add functions as I mentioned then it will work.